# VkLongPoll не считывается хостингом и консолью

Tags: python, вконтакте

Выходит следующая ошибка на хостинге:

```
*File "/home/dxrbxr/python_script_bot.py", line 2, in <module>
    from vk_api.longpoll import VklongPoll, VkEventType
ImportError: cannot import name 'VklongPoll' from 'vk_api.longpoll' (/home/dxrbxr/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/vk_api/longpoll.py)*
```

Вот сам код:

```
import vk_api
from vk_api.longpoll import VklongPoll, VkEventType
from toks import main_token

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token = '*здесь мой токен*')
session_api = vk_session.get_api()
longpoll = VklongPoll(vk_session)

def sender(text):
    vk_session.method('messages.send', {'user_id' : id, 'message' : text, 'random_id' : 0})

for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
        if event.to_me:

            msg = event.text.lower()
            id = event.user_id

            if msg == '/команды':
                sender(id, 'Список команд:\nЗаработок - /работы - /работать, /казино, /бизнесы - /бизнес.')
```

Естественно, это только часть кода, мне предстоит еще его писать.

Я хотел залить на хостинг и проверить лишь одну команду, чтобы понять, работает ли она и стоит ли делать по такому принципу.

Буду рад помощи.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте для упрощенного импорта данный код:

```
from vk_api.longpoll import *
from vk_api.utils import *
```

Эта часть кода импортирует нужные вам классы/объекты и тому подобные значения.